# JComponent isn't setting position nor text

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jcomponent

in the code below I just wish to assign locations and text to my button components on a JFrame, however it always assigns them to be the height of the screen and squashed to the left without displaying the text I assigned. Care for any help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Main
{
    public static final String SIMULATOR_NAME = "Flocking Simulator 2K16"; //Simulator window name.
    private static final String SPARROW_GRAPHIC = "Bird.png"; //Graphic image for sparrows.
    public static final int MAXIMUM_WIDTH = 800; //Simulator window width.
    public static final int MAXIMUM_HEIGHT = 600; //Simulator window height.

    private static final int DEFAULT_BIRDS = 50; //Default number of birds on program launch.
    private static final int MINIMUM_BIRDS = 5; //Minimum quantity of birds.
    private static final int MAXIMUM_BIRDS = 100; //Maximum quantity of birds.
    private static final double DEFAULT_VELOCITY = 0.25; //Move at 0.25 pixels per 1ms.
    private static final int MOVEMENT_DELAY = 5; //Update movement every 5ms.
    private static final int MOVEMENTS_UNTIL_NEXT_UPDATE = 5; //Update directions every 25ms.

    private static JFrame frame; //Frame used from the JFrame class to draw graphics onto.

    private static Flock sparrows; //The flock of sparrows used for the simulator.

    private static JButton addBird; //The button object for adding a bird.
    private static JButton removeBird; //The button object for adding a bird.

    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        Initialize();
        GameLoop();
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame(SIMULATOR_NAME + " - Number Of Birds: " + DEFAULT_BIRDS);
        frame.setSize(MAXIMUM_WIDTH, MAXIMUM_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        LoadObjectGraphics();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void LoadObjectGraphics()
    {
        sparrows = new Flock(SPARROW_GRAPHIC, DEFAULT_BIRDS, new CartesianCoordinate(MAXIMUM_WIDTH, MAXIMUM_HEIGHT), DEFAULT_VELOCITY);

        for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_BIRDS; i++)
        {
            frame.add(sparrows.GetBird(i).BirdGraphic());
        }

        LoadUI();
    }

    private static void LoadUI()
    {
        addBird = new JButton("+");
        addBird.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        removeBird = new JButton("-");
        removeBird.setSize(48, 48);
        removeBird.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        frame.add(addBird);
        frame.add(removeBird);
    }

    private static void UpdateUI()
    {
        frame.setTitle(SIMULATOR_NAME + " - Number Of Birds: " + sparrows.GetMaximumBirds());
    }

    private static void GameLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //Change the directions of the birds
            sparrows.UpdateDirections();

            //Move the birds before updating directions of the birds again
            for (int i = 0; i < MOVEMENTS_UNTIL_NEXT_UPDATE; i++)
            {
                Utils.pause(MOVEMENT_DELAY); //Pause allowing program to not crash in an infinate loop
                sparrows.ProcessMovement(MOVEMENT_DELAY); //Move the birds each interval
                UpdateUI(); //Update the simulators UI
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[As you can see, the dimensions and location of the buttons are incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWIxQ.png)

Comment: You can use this [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridLayoutDemo.java) from Oracle. Read about how to use GridLayout [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). The GridLayout that you created is of no use. You did not specify the size of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridLayout(The simplest way to do this) or a SpringLayout.

An example:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(/*Number of rows*/ , /*Number of columns*/);
```

Add this layout at the frame with:

```
myFrame.setlayout(layout);
```

And add your components at the GridLayout:

```
layout.add(myComponent);
layout.add(mySecondComponent);
```

etc...

There is a complete guide of GridLayout for you:

[How to use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

And a guide of SpringLayout (Is hard to use SpringLayout, but try):

[How to use SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html)

The SpringLayout is better than GridLayout!